# Print output values in ascending order in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, integer

I have an assignment where I am kinda stuck on the following problem:
Read any 3 random numbers from the keyboard and then print them in ascending order.

restrictions:
/data type - int
/only using if-else statements

I have already submitted 2 solutions for this problem:
1st -> the hard way, by manually setting if-else condition for all 6 cases with an output for every single statement, ex:

```
if ((A <= B) && (B <= C));
cout << A << " " << B << " " << C;
etc
```

2nd: using the swap function for swapping the values/ however, I was not supposed to solve it this way..

```
if ( A > B )
swap ( A,B);
if ( A > C )
swap ( A,C);
if ( B > C )
swap (B,C);
cout<< A <<" "<< B <<" "<< C;
```

I have been required a 3rd solution where I have to meet the following criteria:
again, only using the if-else statements :(
also, here I can use an auxiliary variable for changing the values between variables, so at the end to have in 'a' the min, in 'b' medium and in 'c' the max number and display only once the numbers

I do understand this might be a very simple problem for others, and I am not expecting the full answer, but I would really appreciate if someone can give me a more accurate clue on how to solve this as requested - in the more efficient way

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea here is to use your first solution, then try to group the identical condition together. I imagine you have something like:

```
if(A < B && B < C) cout << A << B << C;
if(C < A && A < B) cout << C << A << B;
```

Notice how part of the condition are identical `A < B`. Then you can group them like:

```
if(A < B){
    if(B < C) cout << A << B << C;
    else if(C < A) cout << C << A << B;
}
```

which could also be transformed to:

```
if(A < B){
    if(A < C) {
        if(B < C) cout << A << B << C;
    }
    else cout << C << A << B;
}
```

for easier understanding of the next part. Notice how I changed the `else if` statement to only an `else`, and move the `if` clause to the previous line.

---

Note that:

```
if(A < C && C < B) cout << A << C << B;
```

also follows the rule `A < B`, despite it's not shown directly, but you induce it easily.

Meanwhile, `A < B && A < C` and `A < C && C < B` also share the property of `A < C`, so you can also group them together.

In the end, you will get something like this for the first half:

```
if(A < B){
    if(A < C){
        if(B < C) cout << A << B << C;
        else cout << A << C << B;
    else cout << C << A << B;
}
```

The second half should be pretty similar to this, but will be your homework I guess :D

---

However, personally I would use your method 1 instead of this, as the intentions and conditions are more clear in that way.

Comment: thanks :) this is great and quite similar to my 1st solution indeed
however, they require that I must use an auxiliary variable so that I can change the values between the variables in such a way so at the end I must have in 'a' the minimum, in 'b' medium and in 'c' the maximum number and only print the numbers once, by using only one cout<< at the very end of all statements..